# ¿Cómo podría instanciar un objeto con parámetros que también son clases?

Tags: java, constructor

Estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
Ojos o;
o = new Ojos(Ojos.AZULES);
Sospechoso s;
s = new Sospechoso("Felipe", img, o);
```

Ojos.Azules en la clase Ojos es esto:

```
public final static int MARRONES=0, AZULES=1, OSCUROS=2 ;
```

Me gustaría crear el objeto s así más o menos:

```
s = new Sospechoso("Felipe",img,Ojos.AZULES);
```

Pero solo me funciona así;

```
s = new Sospechoso("Felipe",img, new Ojos(Ojos.AZULES));
```

Me dice que son tipos incompatibles ya que la clas `Ojos` tiene un `int` como único campo. ¿Sabéis como podría hacerlo para no tener un constructor tan largo (tengo muchos parámetros) y poder poner VALORES ya predefinidos?

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñarnos el constructor de Sospechoso?

Comment: Rescuerda marcar tu pregunta como respondida si te fué útil para que otro pueda aprovecharla también. Utiliza la ayuda si no sabes [answer]

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres hacer eso tienes que cambiar tu contructor de Sospechoso a esto:

```
public Sospechoso(String nombre, Imagen img, int ojos){
    //Dejas la asignación de nombre e imagen igual y cambias la de ojos
    this.ojos = new Ojos(ojos);
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me has sido de gran utilidad.  
Un saludo,
Enrique.

Answer (score 2):

Usa un enum. Sirven precisamente para evitar que uses constantes para representar valores discretos.

```
public enum ColorOjos { // este nombre es más claro.
  MARRONES,
  AZULES,
  OSCUROS;
}
```

Al definir un enum, es como si crearas una clase y automáticamente una instancia por cada uno de sus valores; sólo se crea una instancia por cada valor en la JVM. Puedes añadir métodos y atributos, por ejemplo, si necesitas convertir a `int` en algun momento:

```
public enum ColorOjos { // este nombre es más claro.
  MARRONES(0),
  AZULES(1),
  OSCUROS(2);

  private int valor;

  ColorOjos(int valor) {
    this.valor =
      valor;
  }

  public int convertir() {
    return
      this.valor;
  }
}
```

Y luego hacer:

```
ColorOjos colorOjos = Ojos.AZULES;
int intColor1 = colorOjos.convertir();
int intColor2 = Ojos.AZULES.convertir();
```

Otras ventajas es que compruebas los valores en tiempo de compilación (por ejemplo, usando un int si haces `new Ojos(56)` sólo puedes capturar el error en tiempo de ejecución, mientras que con `enum` sólo puedes pasar los valores definidos en el enum, y que los `switch` con `enum` te suelen mostrar un warning si hay algún valor que no consideras.